# Save basic authentication value on shared preferences so on auto login data is fetched

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So i in the fetching of data I have basic auth, so for the first time that the user logs in I need to take the basic authentication like value which is normally like : Basic (then some numbers), so I need to take that and store that inside the local storage. T

he reason why I need to do this is that the next screen after login is going to be a screen where data is being fetched, so I need to save the basic auth token inside the local storage so when the user closes the app and comes back I can pass the basic auth token and get the data from the API.

On the app the authorization is from the response. statusCode, so in order to get data from API I need. So what I require is for the first time the first screen will be the login screen, when the user successfully logs in, we need to get the basic auth token save it on local storage, then use that same token on basic auth, so the data is returned to the other screen successfully, and in 'authorization': basicAuth.toString(), we can do like boolVariable ? prefs.getString('keyName') : basicAuth.toString().

Any help would be really appreciated, and when you guys explain implementation of the code would be even better.

```
// dataset_Working_Location.dart

late Response response2;

TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
String? basicAuth;

Future<Response> fetchWorkingLocationData() async {
  var url = 'https://dev.api.wurk.skyver.co/api/locations';

   basicAuth = 'Basic ' +
      base64Encode(
        utf8.encode('${emailController.text}:${passwordController.text}'),
      );
  response2 = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth.toString()},
  );

  return response2;
}

//dataset_employees.dart

late Response response1;

Future<Response> fetchAccountData() async {
  var url = 'https://dev.api.wurk.skyver.co/api/v1/employees/account';

  response1 = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth.toString()},
  );

  return response1;
}

//login submit button

ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                setState(() {
                  loading = true;
                });
                Future<Response> futureResponse = fetchWorkingLocationData();
                futureResponse
                    .then((response) => {
                          if (response.statusCode == 200)
                            {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Page1()),
                              )
                            }
                          else
                            {
                              setState(() {
                                try {
                                  loading = false;
                                } on Exception catch (e, s) {
                                  loading = true;
                                }
                              }),
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                const SnackBar(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                                  content: Text(
                                    "Incorrect phone number or password",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                  duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
                                ),
                              ),
                            },
                        })
                    .catchError((error, stackTrace) => print('shush'));
              }
              fetchAccountData();
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing values in DevicePreferences? This is a simple process (irrespective of your decision to persist information on disk/files).

Comment: would that be better than using shared prefs